# Multi line regex

Tags: regex, multiline

I've read many items on the topic, but didn't manage to find my solution. So I go with a very simple exemple of what I want:

I have this text:

aaz

bby

ccx

ddw

eev

ffu

ggt

hhw

I want to extract everything in between aa and the first occurence of w. The closest I come to this is **a([^;]*)w** that give me eveyrthing in between aa and the last occurence of w.

What would be the correct version of the regex to get what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `aa([^;]*?)w` would work and so would `aa([^;w]*)w`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `w` in the square brackets:

```
a([^;w]*)w
```